# Standard EBNF grammar of JsonPath

Tags: grammar, jsonpath

I wan't to implement my own JsonPath library but I can not find standard definition of its grammar. I found https://github.com/kevinbirch/kanabo/blob/master/jsonpath.ebnf but it look like much more complicated. Where can I find the complete version of JsonPath grammar?

Comment: Have also looked for this. I don't think there is one.

Answer (score 2):

The closes thing I can find is the PostgreSQL Bison grammar, and the SQL/JSON proposal. It's not EBNF but it may serve your purpose.

PostgreSQL Bison grammar:

- https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/0af302af40669d9bc6de7a202e4723fee39d9376/src/backend/utils/adt/jsonpath_gram.y

SQL/JSON proposal (with BNF grammar):

- https://www.wiscorp.com/pub/DM32.2-2014-00025r1-sql-json-part-2.pdf